# How to use ngDialog properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating web app using angular js and node js. I am using ngDialog in my app. But I got error:

```
Error: a.on is not a function
this.$get</A.activate@http://localhost:4300/js/lib/ng-dialog/js/ngDialog.min.js:2:1673
this.$get</B.open/</<@http://localhost:4300/js/lib/ng-dialog/js/ngDialog.min.js:2:8374
timeout/timeoutId<@http://localhost:4300/js/lib/angular/angular.js:9391:28
completeOutstandingRequest@http://localhost:4300/js/lib/angular/angular.js:2986:7
Browser/self.defer/timeoutId<@http://localhost:4300/js/lib/angular/angular.js:3266:7
```

Here is my code:

```
function DashboardCtrl($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams,HomeOwners,ngDialog) {
     $scope.changeImage = function (id) {
console.log(ngDialog) // code works fine here
        ngDialog.open({
        template: '<p>my template</p>',
        plain: true
    });
}
```

Please Help

Comment: Have you loaded ngDialog like this way var app = angular.module('exampleApp', ['ngDialog']);

Comment: @ Shohel Yes I have loaded. when I console ngDialog it shows me json data

Comment: Try to use ngDialog.js not min version